# JSON response with all columns for a many-to-many relation in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am using two models in Laravel which are linked via a many-to-many relation. The models are `Pictures` and `Labels`. The migration file for `Labels` is

```
class CreateLabelsTable extends Migration {
    public function up() {
        Schema::create('labels', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('name', 128);
            $table->enum('type', [ 'text' , 'contact' ]);
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
    public function down() {
        Schema::dropIfExists('labels');
    }
}
```

Within the model for `Picture` I defined

```
class Picture extends Model {
    public function labels() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Label')
            ->withTimestamps();
    }
}
```

Within the controller I can now use the following PHP code

```
$ptrPicture = Picture::findorfail(3); // '3' is an example of an id here 
return response()->json($ptrPicture->labels()->pluck('id')->toArray());
```

which for example results in `[5, 6, 9]` for the ids of the `Labels` which are connected to `Picture(3)`. This works nicely but now I don't want to return the ids of the `Label` only, but all the columns for the `Label`. How do I manage to get something returned like the following with Laravel?

```
[
    { id: 5, name: 'foo', type: 'text' },
    { id: 6, name: 'bar', type: 'text' },
    { id: 9, name: 'etc', type: 'contact' }
]
```

With `pluck` I can only return one of the columns? How do I return all three columns?

UPON REQUEST ... here are my other migration files:

```
class CreatePicturesTable extends Migration {
    public function up() {
        Schema::create('pictures', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('filename', 256);
            $table->string('description', 4096)->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
    public function down() {
        Schema::dropIfExists('pictures');
    }
}

class CreateLabelPictureTable extends Migration {
    public function up() {
        Schema::create('label_picture', function (Blueprint $table) {

            $table->bigInteger('label_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('label_id')
                ->references('id')
                ->on('labels')
                ->onDelete('cascade');

            $table->bigInteger('picture_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('picture_id')
               ->references('id')
                ->on('pictures')
                ->onDelete('cascade');

            $table->timestamps();

        });

    }
    public function down() {
        Schema::dropIfExists('label_picture');
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you tried removing the `pluck`?

Comment: `return $ptrPicture->labels;`

Comment: Hi Felippe Duarte: I tried to remove `pluck`, but then I get the following error: "Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany::toArray()". Do you have a different advice?

Comment: Hi lufc. Using `return $ptrPicture->labels;` (i. e. without the brackets) results in an SQL error: "SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column ... where 'label_picture'.'picture_id' = 3)". Do you have a different advice?

Comment: You can just do something like this: `$ptrPicture->labels()->get()->toArray() `

Comment: Hi Oleg Nurutdinov. Doing this results in an SQL error: "SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column ... where 'label_picture'.'picture_id' = 3)". Do you have a different advice?

Comment: Ok, Steevie. Can you update your question with labels, puctures and pivot table migrations?

Comment: Hi Oleg Nurutdinov. I edited my questions by adding the two migration files at the end of my post. Any help highly appreciated.

Comment: Hi lufc and Oleg Nurutdinov. With a comment from Maksim Ivanov I found a mistake in my model. After having solved this, your solutions worked. Many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either of the following will do the job.

```
$ptrPicture->labels->toArray(); // note the absence of brackets after 'labels'

// OR

$ptrPicture->labels()->get()->toArray();
```

[Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many)

Comment: Hi Maksim Ivanov. Unfortunately this does not work. For both suggestions I receive an SQL error: "SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column ... where 'label_picture'.'picture_id' = 3)". Do you have a different advice?

Comment: Hi Maksim Ivanov. The full error message is "SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'label_picture.type' in 'field list' (SQL: select 'labels'.*, 'label_picture'.'picture_id' as 'pivot_picture_id', 'label_picture'.'label_id' as 'pivot_label_id', 'label_picture'.'type' as 'pivot_type', 'label_picture'.'created_at' as 'pivot_created_at', 'label_picture'.'updated_at' as 'pivot_updated_at' from 'labels' inner join 'label_picture' on 'labels'.'id' = 'label_picture'.'label_id' where 'label_picture'.'picture_id' = 3)"
exception: "Illuminate\Database\QueryException". Does this help?

Comment: @Steevie, why is it trying to pull 'type' from the pivot table?

Comment: Hi Maksim Ivanov. You made my day. I reviewed it and saw that I included the wrong model for `Pictures`. I had `return $this->belongsToMany('App\Piclabel')->withPivot('type')->withPivot('contact_id')->withTimestamps();` in my previous code, altered this a while ago, but as I included a different file, I was making a mistake.

Comment: @Steevie, glad you found it :)

Comment: Hi Maksim Ivanov. Many thanks again. Could you just edit your above answer so that I can turn the current -1 into a +1?

Comment: Hi Maksim Ivanov. Currently I cannot give a +1 for your useful answer as I unfortunately clicked wrongly. If you could just slightly edit your answer, I could revert my mistake. Would be great. And thanks again.

Comment: @Steevie, done. I wouldn't worry that much about it though :)